# Opening external link without losing session in Cordova

Tags: cordova, session, cordova-plugins, session-cookies, inappbrowser

I have a cordova application in which the user is logged in. Now, the idea is that users can click some links on the app and that they will be opened in the browser of the smartphone (for another parts of website and to download some files). Using InAppBrowser plugin, I placed the links as follows:

In js:

```
window.open(this.getBasicLinkForDocuments + '/ssffilemanager.cgi/doc/get?D_ID=' + someIdParameter, '_system');
```

in main.js:

```
window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open
```

This is working very well. The link is opened in the browser of the smartphone. However, user is no more logged in as in the app, so the user should login manually one more time, which should not be the case.

Is there a way to keep the session in browser to be sure that login is no more needed?

Comment: Couldn't find any solution but if the aim is downloading a file from external server with your current session, it is adviced to use a combination of `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` and `cordova-plugin-file-opener2`